# Slow performance of uploading data using Httpurlconnection in android

Tags: android, upload, httpurlconnection, outputstream, processing-efficiency

I am trying to upload some user input information, text and an image (converted into base64 string) to the server. I am using httpurlconnection to accomplish this, but the performance is very slow. The image size is 600 X 600, and its taking about 119-125seconds to perform the upload, which is a lot.
Here is my code -

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
     public MyClass(String url_string.......) {
     thread.start();
     }

     @Override
     public void run()
     {
         String response = executeRequest();
         parseResponse(response);
     }
}

            URL url_string = prepareURL(url_string, method);
            url = new URL(url_string);
            httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(25000);
            httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
     //method variable in the above line is just a string constant (GET or POST)

            if(method.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.POST)) {
                httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            }

          //toUseJson variable is us just a boolean to determine whether 
          //we have to set the chunking or fixedstreaming mode, 
          //based on GET method or POST method

            if(toUseJson) {
                //httpUrlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(json_message.getBytes().length);
                //httpUrlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024*8);
                httpUrlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            }

            httpUrlConnection.connect();

            System.out.println("start - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(toUseJson) {
                output_stream = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedOutputStream buffered_output_stream = new BufferedOutputStream(output_stream);
                System.out.println("the bytes to read - " + json_message.getBytes().length);
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(json_message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];
                int count = 0;

                System.out.println("middle - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                while((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    System.out.println("count - " + count);
                    buffered_output_stream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }

                output_stream.flush();
            }
```

........

I am trying various combinations to bring down the upload time, but, it always takes around 110-120 seconds.
The number of bytes that the json message is - 907237 bytes

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered doing the upload asyncronously?

Comment: Does this happen on an emulator or actual device?

Comment: @Blaine : yes, it is done on a separate thread.

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak : it is done on a device, samsung galaxy nevus

Comment: I don't see an asyncronous call. Using another thread doesn't necessarily mean it's asyncronous.

Comment: @Blaine : I havent pasted my entire code, its quite long, so, have edited to show the jist of what I am doing. The upload is being done on a separate thread.

Comment: Is it slow on wi-fi or just data network?

Comment: Keep in mind you are trying to send around 600x600x4 bytes of data depending on the image format, what format is the image in? the size is 1,37MB which can be fairly slow when uploading. How much does it take?

Comment: @JanBo : its data network, but i guess it should take around 20 seconds, which is pretty decent for a data network upload.

Comment: @JanBo : its s JPEG image..and the same app (iPhone version) does the same in about 25 seconds, on a data network connection.. do you see any flaws in the code that i posted.

Comment: @JanBo : when i say same app (iPhone version), its a native app, talking to the same server.

Comment: Well at first glance no, but i dont get it, is executeRequest() in run(),actually the code that is bellow the one that is doing the download? I was doing the same thing using HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(url..... and using ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler); to download JSON data and byte data for downloading images. But it should do the same work, maybe try it out it wont take you more then 15min to rewrite the code for testing.

Comment: @JanBo : yes, the download code, is the one that is being called in executeRequest()

Comment: @JanBo : I was using DefaultHttpClient() before, but its not as efficient as HttpUrlConnection. HttpUrlConnection is lightweight and more efficient, I use it for other small requests, but for big ones, it takes time (which it shouldn't)

Comment: But have you tried using it in this particular case? If not i am thinking you try it out to see if it performs better that your code(since it is highly optimized at its core for performing common single network operations), if so then there is something definitely wrong in the way you wrote it.

Comment: @JanBo : Yes, i have tried using it in this particular case. The app, currently uses HttpClient, and I am rewriting the entire network framework to use HttpUrlConnection instead. I have seen the results, and HttpUrlConnection performs faster than HttpClient, but I am sure that there is something wrong in my implementation above. Something related to the buffer size or something.

Comment: @Android-er-naut have you found a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your buffer size to 1024 instead of 1024*1024.

1024B is 1KB, so copy it 1KB at a time.

You were allocating 1024*1024 which is 1024KB=1MB which isnt so graceful in android ;)

Comment: Will try now and let you know the time it took. Thanks for your input

Comment: Its too slow, I checked the online documentation of Android, and it says that if I use - `OutputStream output_stream = new BufferedOutputStream(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());` and simply do `output_stream.write(bytes);` then the internal implementation of write() has a buffer size of 8kb.

Comment: tried 16KB as the buffer size. still takes almost the same time. Just does'nt make sense.